# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'. MercadoPago

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

Good day everyone, I have the following problem, when compiling the project I get an error saying: ERROR in src / app / cart / cart.component.ts (63.25): error TS2304: Cannot find name ' require '.
I have tried implementing npm install --save @ types / node
Also checking the tsconfig.app.json configuration but still the error persists. How can I solve that?
I'm developing everything with Angular.
I appreciate any help

```
 const mercadopago = require('mercadopago');
    mercadopago.configure({
      access_token: 'Your key'
    });
    let preference = {
      items: [
        {
          title: 'Mi producto',
          unit_price: 100,
          quantity: 1,
        }
      ]
    };
    mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
      .then(function (response) {
        this.global.init_point = response.init_point;
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: `mercadopago` is one Node.js API. So you need to create one Node.js aplication and use it in our backend implementation. Seams to me that you're using in our Angular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is `require`. The use of `require` is not supported since Angular 8. You have to use es imports.

`import * as mercadopago from 'mercadopago'`

That's on one side.

It seems to me that `mercadopago` is a server-side library. It might not work if it depends on nodeJS internally. Also, the fact that you are bundling your `access_token` is another indicator that something is wrong.

Comment: It happens that this code is from the MercadoPago page and that's how it was when I tried to implement it, import its libraries and everything, but if it is directly NodeJs,  I will do it like this or with another language

Thank you so much for taking the time to respond!